# Merging list objects in python

Tags: python

I have a pickle file having many objects. I need to have one proper object by combining all the other objects in the file. How can I do that. I tried using many commands, but none seems to work.

```
objs = []

while True:
    try:
        f = open(picklename,"rb")
        objs.append(pickle.load(f))
        f.close()
    except EOFError:
        break
```

Like the one above as shown.

OBJECT stored image :

```
<nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier object at 0x7fb172819198>
<nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier object at 0x7fb1719ce4a8>
<nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier object at 0x7fb1723caeb8>
<nltk.classify.naivebayes.NaiveBayesClassifier object at 0x7fb172113588>
```

Comment: How did you pickle these objects? That will affect how you unpickle them.

Comment: @user2357112 I pickled them using `pickle.dump(nltk.NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set),f)`. Where I am using the NLTK toolkit.

Comment: No, I mean how did you pickle multiple of these objects? If your pickling code made the kind of mistake your unpickling code is making, your file likely only has one classifier pickled in it.

Comment: @user2357112 I appended the objects in the same file using `open(filename,"ab")`.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [`.extend()`](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html) to append all items in the list to `objs`:

*(Assuming `pickle.load(f)` returns a list of objects)*

```
objs.extend(pickle.load(f))
```

Comment: Thank You sir for your answer. Sir I am storing objects in my pickle, which are `NaiveBayesClassifier` object provided in nltk, so when I run using the above code I get `TypeError: 'NaiveBayesClassifier' object is not iterable`

Comment: What does `pickle.load(f)` return exactly? It returns a single `NaiveBayesClassifier` object or a list of `NaiveBayesClassifier` objects?

Comment: Sir I edited the answer showing the result of printing `pickle.load(f)`